# Android CustomView integrated in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a draw application. For this I have created a Custom DrawingView. To enable additional options during the drawing, the CustomView should be included in the activity_main.xml in a specific area.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawingView dv ;
private Paint mPaint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

    dv = new DrawingView(this, mPaint);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
} 
}
```

.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

public int width;
public  int height;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint, mPaint;
Context context;
private Paint circlePaint;
private Path circlePath;

public DrawingView(Context c, Paint pPaint) {
    super(c);
    context=c;

    mPaint = pPaint;
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePath = new Path();
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
    canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    circlePath.reset();
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.DrawingView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But if I try this, there is always an InflateException thrown

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: de.sentoon.touchtesterv4, PID: 11743
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.sentoon.touchtesterv4/de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.DrawingView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1503)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.DrawingView
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.DrawingView
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:618)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6745)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1503)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: add this in Parent Linear Layout Tag   =                                                                          xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

You have not declared enough constructors.

Normally custom view shoud have at least 2 constructors. One accepts `Context`, the other `Context` and `AttributeSet`.

```
public class DravingView extends View {
    public DravingView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DravingView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

**Why do I need that constructor?**

First the `xml` is being parsed, and then the appropriate class object is being created. After parsing the layout `xml` file, framework would try to create `DrawingView` object for you with applied parameters in `xml`. Those parameters are being passed through `AttributeSet`. But as long as it cannot find such a constructor in `DrawingView` class, it crashes.

Comment: Thanks! If I added the second constructor and set the paint default in the constructors it worked!

Comment: Fine! As a newcomer of the community - when you receive an answer to your question, you should mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `DrawingView` constructor to this

```
public DrawingView(Context c, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(c, attr);
    context=c;
}
```

Add this method to your `DrawingView` class

```
public void setPaint(Paint pPaint) {
        mPaint = pPaint;
    }
```

add ID to drawing view in xml
`<de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/drawingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150sp" />`

then initialize drawingView like this
`dv = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawingView);`

Then set your paint like this in Activity
`dv.setPaint(mPaint);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But if I tried this it called a
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.DrawingView.setPaint(android.graphics.Paint)' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you initialize `DrawingView` first like this `dv = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawingView);` then call the set paint method. if so did you add the id to drawingView in xml and is this the path to your `DrawingView` `de.sentoon.touchtesterv4.DrawingView` coz that can also be the problem... if you still having problems then post your full `Activity`, `DrawingView` and layout file